# Search peoples by interest?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I search people by according to their interests? Is there any feature in the Graph API, or is there any API available to do this?

I need to integrate this feature with my php project, so kindly let me know if it is possible with php.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so yet, because it's still a beta feature that you can enable through your account. Meaning that not everybody is using it yet, so not many results will be shown if that api was available now.